# Selenium Webscraper with Python won't let me click an element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to put together a web scraper to get locations by zip code entered by the user. As of right now I am able to navagate to the website but I am not able to click on the drop down button that allows you to enter in a zip code. Here is what I have so far

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

zipcode = input("What zip code would you like to search? ")
out_table = 'Oreilly_autp_parts_addresses_{}.csv'.format(zipcode)

#Using Selenium to navigate to website, search zipcode and get html data
driver = webdriver.Chrome() #requires geckodriver.exe
driver.get('https://www.oreillyauto.com/')
time.sleep(2)
driver.maximize_window()
el = driver.find_element_by_class_name("site-store")
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class','site-store site-nav_item dispatcher-trigger--active')", el)
```

It seems to be clicking on the correct element but the drop down that is supposed to show up isn't there. [HTML Code Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pueEI.png)

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I think that site is detecting webdriver and not allowing certain behavior.  When I launch it without webdriver I can click the store locator, but if I launch the browser with chromedriver I cannot manually click it.

Comment: Yeah I've noticed that too. Do you think that means its not possible to automate this site?

Comment: There are posts on how to get around the detection. Just depends how much time you are willing to spend.

Comment: @Ywapom could you possibly point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver